# How do i remove the "Pre-LockScreen" before pattern unlock on Android 9.0

Tags: lock-screens, 9.0-pie

Is it possible to remove the "Pre-Lock Screen" on android 9.0. Basically when i press the power button to wake my phone what displays is a Grey Co loured Lock Screen showing the time and Date, if i scroll this up it then asks me to fingerprint unlock or pattern unlock.

Kind of annoying because if i want to glance at my notifications i need to first swipe up, then when it requests the pattern hit the back button to display my lockscreen background and my notifications ect.

The First Image display the Pre-lock i want to remove and the third is where i want it to be whenever i press my power button to wake my phone

[image: Pre-Lock Screen]
[image: Pattern Unlock where i can press back]
[image: Lockscreen]

Comment: I don't know if this is the standard behavior of Android 9.0 Pie or vendor's customization, but just in case this is device-dependent, could you provide the phone model?